# Can I send announcement via Slack that require acknowledgements?

Tags: slack, slack-api

We'd like to use Slack to send announcements to a certain group with the `@abc` syntax, but that always requires everyone to *acknowledge* the message so people can't claim they didn't see it. Maybe just that they reply with the thumbs up emoji.

Is there a way to do this *and* see who hasn't acknowledged yet?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is possible. Here is a broad outline of two approaches on how to implement it:

## Buttons approach

Have a confirm button in your announcement message via [message buttons](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-buttons).
When the user clicks the button your app will receive that info and can log it.
In addition your app can reply to the user (e.g. with a direct message or ephemeral message) to acknowledge that he confirmed.
Or if you want more transparency your app can update your announcement message with the list of all users that clicked on confirm.

## Reactions approach

Your requirement can also be achieved with reactions (e.g. thumbs up emoji). For that just ask the user to react to your announcement message accordingly, maybe add a dummy reaction to start. It will then be visible to everyone who reacted to your announcement. In addition you can let your bot listen to those reactions (via [Events API](https://api.slack.com/events-api), [`reaction_added`](https://api.slack.com/events/reaction_added) event) and log all confirms.

However there is a caveat: This approach also allow users to remove their reactions again. So if you want accountability I would go with the buttons approach.